# Azure: VM's not assigned fault or update domains

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

I provisioned a few Azure VM's in an Availability set using the Azure Java SDK. The VM deployed successfully and is running. However, one of the VM's, the one provisioned first, does not display a fault domain or an update domain.

Why is my VM not being assigned a fault domain or an update domain?

[image]

Comment: You could get fault domain and update on Portal `Resource group`-->Availability set-->Virtual Machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my VM not being assigned a fault domain or an update domain?

No, your VM is in an availability set. Your availability set name is `SG-*`. When VM in an availability set, it will assign a fault domain and update domain automatic.

You could get your VM's fault domain and update domain value on Azure Portal.
`Resource group-->Availability set-->Virtual Machines`
[image]

Update:

> However, one of the VM's, the one provisioned first, does not display
>   a fault domain or an update domain.

Based on my knowledge, it is a design behavior. The first VM's fault domain and update domain is `0 0`. You could all domain on `Availability set`.

Comment: but why does it show for all other VM's but not only one VM

Comment: @nwarriorch Yes, it will show all VMs, in my lab, I only have one VM in the availability set.

Comment: @nwarriorch Sorry for my mistake, do you mean other VMs show fault domain but firstly VM could not show the fault domain?

Comment: Yes, So all the other VM's show the fault and update domain, one of the VM doesn't show.

Comment: @nwarriorch I test in my lab, I get the same result with you. I think it is a design behavior. The first VM's fault domain and update domain is `0 0`.

Comment: @nwarriorch Could you get the domain on `Availability set` not `VM`. It's ensure your VM has been assign fault domain and update domain.

Comment: Okay, yeah that sounds about right. Thank you that helps, could you update your answer so I can accept?